# Importing JSON in Neo4j using WITH: Invalid input ':'

Tags: json, neo4j

I'm trying to import a JSON into Neo4j.

I'm using something like this:

```
WITH [{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"cdd@fake.com"}],first_name:null,last_name:null},{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"ffd@rotterdam.nl"}],first_name:"Jo",last_name:null},{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"yeh@hdn.nl"}],first_name:"Jenno",last_name:null},{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"doe@doe.com"}],first_name:"John",last_name:"Doe"},{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"me@doe.com"}]
```

But I get this error:

```
Invalid input ':': expected '0'-'9', whitespace or '}' (line 1, column 1763 (offset: 1762))
```

What can it be? I have understood that keys shouldn't be quoted, values can't be "" empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid, it misses some ending brackets at the end, this workded for me :

```
WITH [{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"cdd@fake.com"}],first_name:null,last_name:null},{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"ffd@rotterdam.nl"}],first_name:"Jo",last_name:null},{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"yeh@hdn.nl"}],first_name:"Jenno",last_name:null},{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"doe@doe.com"}],first_name:"John",last_name:"Doe"},{addr:[],phone:[],email:[{value:"me@doe.com"}]}] AS elts
UNWIND elts AS elt
RETURN elt
```

-

```
╒══════════════════════════════╕
│elt                           │
╞══════════════════════════════╡
│{first_name: (null), email: [{│
│value: cdd@fake.com}], last_na│
│me: (null), addr: [], phone: [│
│]}                            │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{first_name: Jo, email: [{valu│
│e: ffd@rotterdam.nl}], last_na│
│me: (null), addr: [], phone: [│
│]}                            │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{first_name: Jenno, email: [{v│
│alue: yeh@hdn.nl}], last_name:│
│ (null), addr: [], phone: []} │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{first_name: John, email: [{va│
│lue: doe@doe.com}], last_name:│
│ Doe, addr: [], phone: []}    │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{addr: [], phone: [], email: [│
│{value: me@doe.com}]}         │
└──────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I see, sorry my data is correctly closed. The sample I posted indeed not. Can it be that `{1:{zipcode:"2338 AAA",housenumber:"302"}}` a number 1 as key is not allowed with Neo4j?

Comment: It isn't supported by the json spec neither by neo4j, actually you are building a map and java maps cannot have key names being non-strings, as it is the same in lot of other languages